# Lecture to solve 2nd order differential equation in matrix form.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

I have an system of three differential equation coupled. I put this system to matrix form. I think it should be more easy to solve.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \ddot x_1 \\ 
    \ddot x_2 \\
    \ddot x_3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & a_{12} & -a_{31} \\ 
    -a_{12} & 0 & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & -a_{23} & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \dot x_1 \\ 
    \dot x_2 \\
    \dot x_3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
    c_1 \\ 
    c_2 \\
    c_3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
All constants are positive or zero.

Could someone tell me what I should read to get the knowledge to solve this differential equation ?

Thanks for your help.
Tof

Edit: $a_{23} -> -a_{23} $

Comment: @LutzL I forget it when I write. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the $A$ matrix is a skew symmetric matrix which represents a vectorial product operator $\vec A \times$ so the DE could read

$$
\ddot X = \vec A \times \dot X + C
$$

So we have

$$
\langle \dot X, \ddot X \rangle = \langle \dot X, C \rangle
$$

because $\langle \dot X, \vec A\times \dot X \rangle = 0$ or

$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\Vert\dot X\Vert^2 = \langle \dot X,C \rangle
$$

and after integration

$$
\Vert\dot X\Vert^2 = 2 \langle X, C \rangle + C_0
$$

which can be arranged as

$$
\big\langle X - X_0(t),C \big\rangle = 0
$$

so the movement is such that $X-X_0(t)$ is normal to $C$
etc.

NOTE

$\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ represents the scalar product between two vectors. Here $X_0(t)$ represents a vector multiplied by the scalar $||\dot X||^2$ plus a constant vector. Now assuming $\Vert C \Vert > 0$

$$
\Vert\dot X\Vert^2 = \left\langle \Vert\dot X \Vert^2\frac{C}{\Vert C \Vert^2},C \right\rangle
$$

and

$$
C_0 = \langle x_0, C \rangle
$$

hence

$$
X_0 =  \Vert\dot X\Vert^2\frac{C}{\Vert C\Vert^2} + x_0
$$

Comment: I don't see how you get from $(1/2)(d/dt) \Vert X \Vert^2 = \langle \dot X, C \rangle$ to $\Vert \dot X \Vert = 2\langle X, C \rangle + C_0$; I understand the right-hand side just fine; but I don't see how the integral of the left is ***anything other than*** $(1/2)(\Vert X  \Vert^2 - \Vert X_0 \Vert^2)$.  Wassup?  Cheers!

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I will fix this typo.

Comment: OK, Thanks for fixing the typo. Also, I should have typed  "***anything other than*** $(1/2)(\Vert \dot X \Vert^2 - \Vert \dot X_0 \Vert)$" in my other comment, but you seem to have straightened your post out despite my mistake.  But now I want to know how you get $\langle X - X_0(t), C \rangle = 0$ from the equation right above it.  Can you show me?  Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. Please see the note attached at the answer bottom.

Comment: What does $X+X_0(t)$ mean? Should that not be $X(t)-X_0$? And if the reference point $X_0$ is not constant in time, how can you claim that the motion follows a plane? Is it not that this type of Lorenz equation has spirals on the surface of a cylinder as solutions?

Comment: I am not claiming that the movement follows a plane. I said that $X-X_0(t)$ is normal to $C$. It is impossible that the movement could result into a movement like Lorentz's because the actual movement is linear, so no chaos is possible. I could solve it explicitly without the focus into the movement qualitative details but I prefer my approach.

Comment: Could you explain me how you get $ \langle \dot X, \ddot X \rangle = \langle \dot X, C \rangle $ . I don't understand how you get the second line from the first line.

Comment: A just disappear from the final equation.  Can we put always $C_0$  to this form $\langle x_0, C \rangle $ ?
Assuming the second line, I understand until integration, and with the help of note I had $ \big\langle 2X - X_0(t),C \big\rangle = 0 $ . Is there a 2 missing ? 
Is $\Vert C\Vert = C  $ because all component of C are positive or null ?

Comment: As far as I know $< \vec u, \vec u \times \vec v > = 0$ and $A = \vec a \times $ All skew symmetric  3$\times$3 can be associated to a vector product. My exposition covers also the case $C = 0$ In this case the movement will result kinetic energy conservative $||\dot X||^2 = C_0$.

Comment: I mean the [Lorentz force of electro-dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force). Like an electron in a static electro-magnetic field.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for the clarification about Lorentz not Lorenz as I cited. The movement qualitatively in the general case, is a kind of spiral "almost"  perpendicular to the $C$ direction.

Comment: @Cesareo Ok, so u replace A by a vector product and because it should exist a vector orthogonal with $ \dot X$, you make $ \langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle $ in both side. Then the term with A is equal to 0. Right ?

Comment: @Tof   Yes. This is the right result.

Answer (score 1):

In
$$
\ddot X=A\times \dot X+C 
$$
you can apply an orthogonal rotation 
$$
U\ddot X=\det(U)^{-1}(UA)\times (U\dot X)+UC.
$$
The rotation $U$ can be chosen so that $UA\sim e_1$. Thus one can assume w.l.o.g. that $A=ae_1$. Then the components of the system read as (set at first $V=\dot X$)
$$
\pmatrix{\dot v_1\\\dot v_2\\\dot v_3}
=a\pmatrix{0\\-v_3\\v_2}+\pmatrix{c_1\\c_2\\c_3}
$$
Integration by standard methods gives
\begin{align}
v_1&=c_1t+b_1\\
v_2&=ab_2\cos(at)-ab_3\sin(at)-\frac{c_3}a&\implies
av_3=c_2-\dot v_2&=c_2+a^2b_2\sin(at)+a^2b_3\cos(at)\\
v_3&=ab_2\sin(at)+ab_3\cos(at)+\frac{c_2}a
\end{align}

Now integrate once again to get $X$,
\begin{align}
x_1&=\frac12c_1t^2+b_1t+d_1\\
x_2&=b_2\sin(at)+b_3\cos(at)-\frac{c_3}at+d_2\\
x_3&=-b_2\cos(at)+b_3\sin(at)+\frac{c_2}at+d_3\\
\end{align}
We get as the result a superposition of an accelerated motion in direction $A=ae_1$ and of a circular and a linear motion in the plane perpendicular to $A$.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you said an orthogonal rotation, you mean to change my axis along the force then I have just one coordinate ? and you called it $ae_1$

Comment: Just added the extra step for general transformations, for $U \in SO(3)$ we have $\det(U)=1$. Set $v_1=A/\|A\|$, $v_2$ orthonormal to $v_1$, $v_3=v_1\times v_2$ then with $V=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ you get $U=V^{-1}$, and there is 1 parameter free in that construction.